# Problems with realloc

Tags: c++, codeblocks, realloc

I'm having some problem with using realloc.
This is mine arrray declared with calloc

```
ptr = (int*) calloc(arraySize, sizeof(int));
```

Later on im using this ptr as an argument in this function:

```
void DeleteElement(int *aArray, int &aArraySize, int aElmntIdx){

    for (int i = 0; i < aArraySize - aElmntIdx; i++){
        *(aArray + aElmntIdx + i - 1) = *(aArray + aElmntIdx + i);
    }
    aArraySize -= 1;
    realloc(aArray, aArraySize * sizeof(int));

}
```

The thing is when i use sizeof before and after calling realloc it shows the same size, does that mean realloc didnt work? How can i fix that?

Comment: I suggest you read e.g. [this `realloc` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc). Pay close attention to what it ***returns***. Then learn about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and throw away your code.

Comment: you shouldn't use `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` in C++ (and this isn't valid C code btw)

Comment: and [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) is not a function, it's an operator and evaluated at **compile-time**

Comment: And as mentioned by @UnholySheep, `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, which means it can not know anything about run-time things like where pointers are pointing. If you use `sizeof` on a pointer, it gives you the size of *the pointer* and not what it points to.

Comment: *when i use sizeof before and after calling realloc it shows the same size* Given `int *ptr = ( int * ) calloc(...)`, then `sizeof( ptr )` returns the size of the *pointer*, not the array of memory it points to.

Comment: @UnholySheep What you say is true in this case. However, there is an exception to that rule; `sizeof` a VLA is evaluated at run-time.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Except that C++ doesn't support variable-length arrays.

Comment: I know I shouldnt use these C functions and wanted to use vectors since beginning but that is what is required from my teacher since we werent introduced to vectors in our classes. Thanks for that reference, I was using different site but this description is much clearer to what the function does.

Comment: This I `c` documentation but it may still help you to understand how to use `realloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/4726/memory-management/4329/reallocating-memory#t=20170308142252895279

Comment: If your teacher requires you to use C style `malloc` instead of C++ `new` you should consider finding another teacher

Comment: @UnholySheep Can you reallocate memory using new? How?

Comment: By dynamically allocating a `new` array and copying all elements of the old one (usually using a `for` loop), then `delete`ing the old one (to avoid memory leaks) - which is essentially the same thing `realloc` does

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There was a C tag on the question when I started commenting.

Comment: Ok so if i send this pointer by reference and then change it to `aArray = (int*) realloc(aArray, aArraySize * sizeof(int));` it should be all good? (Btw I know this is half assed solution, I'm gonna do it again with vectors later on)